# Angular 2 authentication with web api for SPA

Tags: rest, angular, authentication, django-rest-framework

What are the best practices of creating an authentication system for angular 2 SPA. Is there any built-in Angular2 modules to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core thing you need is a guard to prevent routing to pages that require authentication. Thoughtram has a [great article on guards](http://web.archive.org/web/20161120184354/http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/18/guards-in-angular-2.html) and Jason Watmore has [a brilliant post](http://web.archive.org/web/20161025015535/http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/09/29/angular-2-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial) showing a full authentication mechanism using a guard and JSON Web Tokens.

Whether you use JWT (and there are reasons not to) or sessions (and there are reasons not to), it all comes down to the guard.

You write a guard like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor (private router: Router) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        if (isTheUserSignedIn()) {
            return true;
        }

        // If not signed in, navigate to the login page and store the return URL
        this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }});
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then, wherever you configure the routes for your app module, you need to tell the route to use your guard:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    // Protect the Home route using the guard
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    // Don't protect the login and register pages
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
    // Don't protect pages that don't need protecting
    { path: 'some-unprotected-page', component: UnprotectedPageComponent },
    // Default redirect
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

Comment: what are the reasons not to use JWT and Seesions ? what is the best alternative ? I am asking because I use django-rest-framework for the API and the official documentation recommends  using seesions for SPAs. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#sessionauthentication

Comment: @user2080105 Both JWT and sessions have their detractors. I think the main complaint about sessions is that one has to maintain state on the server. And JWT makes it difficult or impossible to expire a session before a set time. I wasn't making a judgement either way, just pointing out that both have their drawbacks. Regardless, this solution works for both.